# PyQt App deployment

Tags: application-development, packaging, debian, pyqt

I'm developing four bioinformatic software's with PyQt. I mostly target Windows OS users but since the programs run without any problems on Ubuntu, I thought to upload them to the USC (I also got several requests).

However, I'm a bit worry whether this makes sense because last year I participated the Ubuntu App Showdown and my app is still pending review.

Is there an easy way to create Debian packages (similar to Quickly) or can I simply upload the source? Is the reviewer process "dead" or not interested in scientific tools? In short, does it makes sense to invest time in deployment to the USC?

Thanks in advance!
Stefanie

Answer (score 1):

> However, I'm a bit worry whether this makes sense because last year I
>   participated the Ubuntu App Showdown and my app is still pending
>   review.

That is a known issue many apps in previous appshowdown is still pending for review as per [Jono Bacon](http://www.muktware.com/5822/ubuntu-launches-second-app-showdown#comment-993090274) 
`It is due to due to the lack of security sandboxing, and complex packaging requirements`

> Is there an easy way to create Debian packages?

There are several guides for debian packaging, If you find it is difficult to follow you can ask help from community. But Ubuntu now moving to another packaging system called click which is very is to manage, But it is not yet available for  non qml apps

> Is the review process "dead" or not interested in scientific tools?

It is not dead yet, It is in the state of transition, and there is no interest loss in scientific apps

**Edit**

Since you use Qt, I suggest porting your app to ubuntu-sdk so that it will support convergence and remove headache of packaging